# Regex difference between " *" and "\s*"

Tags: regex

I'm using regular expressions to match any number of white space characters. Is there a difference between the following?

```
" *"
"\s*"
```

Are there special cases where either would cause an issue?

Comment: what is the language?

Comment: @CássioGalvão Regex is Regex no matter the language. And you don't parse HTML with it, either.

Comment: @Undo That is not entirely true ([see here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)). However, in this case it's pretty safe to say that pretty much all popular regex flavors use `" "` for the space character, and `"\s"` for all whitespace characters.

Comment: Also, the OP may find [this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) helpful.

Comment: @Undo - Where did you get the notion that "regex is regex"? There are [numerous flavors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html). Many have their own quirks and syntax. Check out the [tag:regex] info tab.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`" *"` will only match zero or more of the [SPACE] character and only the [SPACE] character.

`"\s*"` will match zero or more of ANY whitespace character ( SPACE, TAB, FORMFEED, etc. ).

Therefore they are **not** equivalent expressions. `\s` is what you want usually, especially since you can't readily *see* whitespace characters by definition.

Answer (score 3):

This is the difference between the regular space () and any space (space, tab, line breaks, etc.).

See [reference here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).